# PostgreSQL - INSERT INTO statement

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

What I'm trying to do is select various rows from a certain table and insert them right back into the same table. My problem is that I keep running into the whole "duplicate PK" error - is there a way to skip the PK field when executing an INSERT INTO statement in PostgreSQL?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO reviews SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE rev_id=14;
```

the `rev_id` in the preceding SQL is the PK key, which I somehow need to skip. (To clarify: I am using * in the SELECT statement because the number of table columns can increase dynamically).

So finally, is there any way to skip the PK field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you attempting to duplicate a row with a new ID assigned to it? This seems like a really weird thing to want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert only the values you want so your PK will get auto-incremented

```
insert into reviews (col1, col2, col3) select col1, col2, col3 from reviews where rev_id=14
```

Please do not retrieve/insert the id-column

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into reviews (col0, col1, ...) select col0, col1, ... from reviews where rev_id=14;
```

Comment: This is ok, but the reviews columns are increasing dynamically in certain times, in that I cannot exactly say the column name

Comment: @user1023242 Dynamic column names? This is sounding more and more like a data model design problem, not a query problem.